# Already an open DataReader with this connection

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

So basically I have two connections in my application:

```
conn = new MySqlConnection("server=" + ip + ";uid=" + user +";pwd=" + pass + ";database=" + db);
readconn = new MySqlConnection("server=" + ip + ";uid=" + user + ";pwd=" + pass + ";database=" + db);
```

I use `conn` only for execution statements, such as UPDATE and INSERT. Then I use `readconn` only whenever someone joins the server which deals with a SELECT statement.

Then this error occurs with seemingly no pattern to it, other than it's being caused by the same function every time (which does an INSERT query on a transaction on the `conn` connection).

```
There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
```

What I don't understand is, this stack trace shows that this error occurred in a function that uses `conn`, not `readconn`. On `conn` there is never, ever a DataReader being associated with it. It's almost as if there is only one connection, but this is why I specifically open two different connections, one for reading and one for inserting.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated, maybe I'm just missing out on something obvious here.

Comment: Show us the code where you open and use `conn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to close the connection with conn.Close().

Or better, use something like:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
//Your code
}

using (MySqlConnection readConn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
//Your code
}
```

it will close automatically the connection ;)

Comment: Are you implying that I should be creating the connection, executing the query and then closing the connection? I was under the impression that I should maintain an active connection to the database while the program is running, not have to initialize a new connection for every query.

Comment: @JaTochNietDan You should only keep a connection open for the scope of a database transaction not the lifetime of the application.  If you are doing transactions in a loop, keep it open for the duration of the loop.

Comment: I recommend you to open a connection each time. But, it´s up to you. If you open a new connection using "using", at the end of the using you will be sure that the connection willr emain opened.

Comment: @JaTochNietDan The best part of the `using` keyword is that in addition to closing the connection, it will also dispose of the object.  Lots of `SqlConnection` objects are expensive and can cause problems.  So it is *always* best practice to wrap `IDisposable` objects in `using` blocks.

Comment: Interesting. My point of view was that it would seem inefficient to be constantly opening/closing connections. However after reading that link and your explanations, it makes sense now. I'll go ahead and make some changes and assuming it's all sorted (probably will be), I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: We are glad to help ;) Well explained too Evan!